# Shop search based on reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have to do similar web search on e-shop based on this site:
http://frisco.pl/

So far I recognize it as reactJS implementation. Am I correct? I don't know anything about reactJS and am I right that every search item is existing in _resource variable (which is visible in page source), and that's why the searching is so fast?

Also what plugin respond for automatic change of browser URL while typing keyword in search box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this website is made with reactjs.
for automatic change of browser URL, its made with react-router (but you can use other to manage that).

React abstracts away the DOM from you, giving a simpler programming model and better performance.